# How do i change a control location to be in the center of the screen?

Tags: c#

I don't want to change the screen resolution. I have a user control in my Form1 designer when I'm moving the mouse over the control area it's doing:

```
private void graphChart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   graphChart1.ChangeChartSize(600, 600);
   graphChart1.ChangeChartLocation(0, 0);
}

public void ChangeChartSize(int width, int height)
{
   this.Size = new Size(width, height);
   chart1.Size = new Size(width, height); 
   chart1.Invalidate();
}

public void ChangeChartLocation(int x, int y)
{
   this.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

But now the location is 0,0 I want that even if the control size will be bigger then the form it doesn't matter I want that the control will change it's location to the center of the screen or the center of the Form(since the form is in the center already) .

Comment: Just to be clear, you want it to always be in the center of the screen?

Comment: are you wanting to resize the Chart..? if so try the following 
Try something like this 
`chart1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - chart1.Width) / 2 ;`
`chart1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - chart1.Height) / 2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move chart to this location:

```
x = (formWidth - chartWidth) / 2;
y = (formHeight - chartHeight) / 2;
```